# Passing SQL Object into new class

Tags: php

I have an active mysql object that contains my conections etc.. $db->query(my query).
I want to pass this object into a new class so i don't have to create the object again

How would i go about passing it into the new class so it's still active?

```
class NewClass {
  var $db;
  function __construct($db) {
   $this->db=$db;
 }

}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems valid to me. It's one of the three types of dependency injection Martin Fowler [identifies](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html):

- Constructor
- Setter
- Interface

If you wanted, for example, to use setter injection instead of constructor injection, create a setter method on your class to accept the database parameter. It might be worth making the property private too, in order to prevent other code from using objects of `NewClass` as providers of the database object.

```
class NewClass {
  private $db;
  public function setDb($db) {
    $this->db=$db;
  }
}
```